# How do I test if the following attribute is present in xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt

What is the test I would write to see if the thumbnailURL attribute exists for a given record?

```
<record last-modified="Wed, 16 Oct 2013 13:07:24 EDT" mimetype="text/html" url="someURL">
<metadata>
  <meta content="Planning" name="title"/>
  <meta content="12345" name="ccsid"/>
  <meta content="user1234" name="author"/>
  <meta content="Wed Oct 16 13:07:24 EDT 2013" name="pubDate"/>
  <meta content="planning" name="categories"/>
  <meta content="http://thumbnail_182x136.jpg" name="thumbnailURL"/>
</metadata>
<content>
Some description
</content>
</record>
```

Answer (score 1):

If the current context node is the `record` element then something like

```
metadata/meta[@name = 'thumbnailURL']
```

should do the job.  Evaluated as boolean (e.g. in the `test` of an `xsl:if`) this would be true if the `thumbnailURL` meta element exists and false if it doesn't, evaluated as a node set (e.g. in the `select` of an `xsl:variable`) it would give you the set of all `meta` elements under the record whose `name` is `thumbnailURL` or an empty set if there are none.